# How to send the test count displayed at the end of the Jenkins log in email body after test execution?

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am using Maven surefire plugin to trigger testcase's from Jenkins, once the execution is done a report is getting generated at the same time at the end of the build log, I can see the no off passed, failed and skipped tests. 
I want to take this number and send it in the email body form Jenkins. I could be able to send the whole log, but how to read only the pass, fail or skipped count?

Also I would like to read the generated HTML report summary and send it in the email body.